# Why the height of my first row is more than other rows HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why the height of first row `March 2020` of first product `Jiko Supa Eco` is larger than other rows, even though I have fixed it too. ? Before posting the question, I check in developer tools for any blank data, which might be causing the problem, but that's not the case.
Thanks to those helping hands

Here is my HTML code

```
<table>
    <thead class="loanProductsHeader">
        <tr>
            <td>Installment Month</td>
            <td>Due Date</td>
            <td>Installment Amount</td>
            <td>Amount Received</td>
            <td>Payment Date</td>
            <td>Mpesa Code</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let loanInstallments of loanProduct.loanPayments | orderBy: 'dueDate'; index as i ">
        <tr style="max-height:22px;">
            <td>
                {{loanInstallments.dueDate | date:'MMMM yyyy'}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{loanInstallments.dueDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{loanInstallments.installmentAmount | currency:'KES '}}

            </td>
            <td> {{loanInstallments.amountReceived| currency:'KES '}}
            </td>
            <td> {{loanInstallments.dateReceived | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{loanInstallments.receiptNumber}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is `scss` code

```
.mainContainer {
    width: 100%;
    // display: flex;
    // flex-direction: column;
}

mat-card {
    background: unset;
}

mat-card-title {
    margin-top: 3%;
    // margin-bottom: -1%;
    background: #2D4431;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: #2D4431;
    color: white
}

.loanProductsHeader {
    background: lightgray;
    font-size: large;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: initial;
}

.editButton {
    height: 25px;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-button-wrapper {
    vertical-align: super
}
```

[image: Image for better understanding]

Comment: Can you post the full code? Including the ng data (loanProduct,loanData) and the CSS? A code sandbox would be even better.

Comment: I posted my style code, please have look now

Comment: Can't really help here without the data.

Comment: Just use inspector on output page, clear cells (`td`) content of the first `tr` one by one, finally you will find the `td` with most height, than you can fix it.

Comment: Based on the static data, I modified the answer as the padding in box-modal is appearing to be 1px only.

Comment: @M.Abooali how can I fix by that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following knowing I added multiple  as the real data is not available.

CSS

```
td { padding: 10px 0;}
```

HTML

```
<tbody *ngFor="let loanInstallments of loanProduct.loanPayments | orderBy: 'dueDate'; index as i ">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.dueDate | date:'MMMM yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.dueDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.installmentAmount | currency:'KES '}}

                </td>
                <td> {{loanInstallments.amountReceived| currency:'KES '}}
                </td>
                <td> {{loanInstallments.dateReceived | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.receiptNumber}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.dueDate | date:'MMMM yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.dueDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.installmentAmount | currency:'KES '}}

                </td>
                <td> {{loanInstallments.amountReceived| currency:'KES '}}
                </td>
                <td> {{loanInstallments.dateReceived | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.receiptNumber}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.dueDate | date:'MMMM yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.dueDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.installmentAmount | currency:'KES '}}

                </td>
                <td> {{loanInstallments.amountReceived| currency:'KES '}}
                </td>
                <td> {{loanInstallments.dateReceived | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{loanInstallments.receiptNumber}}
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
```

Comment: what did you changed in `html`

Comment: I know the approach to add the rows is not right, but to share an approach, this was only possible due to non-availability of real data or working sample.

Comment: I added td { padding: 10px 0;} in css 

In html, I repeated the single <tr> what you created.

Comment: correct, your approach made the height of all rows equal, but in actual I want to make the height of first row equal to the height of others.

Comment: Does that mean you want the height to be same throughout? If yes, then that what we did. I got confused with your last comment. Its contradicting :P

but in actual I want to make the height of first row equal to the height of others,
Others what ? Other rows ? 

If yes,
then as you said - correct, your approach made the height of all rows equal

Comment: NO, please read carefully, as shown in the image, I want the height of my first row equal to the height of other rows, how do I do this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205175/discussion-between-krishna-tandon-and-lint).

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the screenshot, this does not look like a CSS issue. The whitespace is evenly dispersed and the row looks empty—are you sure you're getting all your data? It looks like some `loanPayments` have null data, i.e. indexes 0 and 2 of your array `loanProduct`.

If this is a valid state for your data, you can use [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) and only render the row if `loanInstallments` is truthy, or if `loanInstallments.dueDate` or `loanInstallments.installmentAmount` (or any of its properties) exist to prevent whitespace from showing.